# Code shows no errors but won't send results

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been stuck trying to find the missing link, the employee's show but the pay won't calculate. I could use the insight as i can't seem to notice what would cause this. I do belive the problem lies in TestEmployee.java.

**Employee.java**

```
package salary;
public abstract class Employee {

    public String fullName;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public abstract double getBiWeeklyPay(); 

    public void printgetBiWeeklyPay() {
       System.out.println("Employee "+this.fullName+ "'s"+ "Bi-weekly pay is:");
    }
}
```

**HourlyEmployee .java**

```
package salary;
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {

    public double hourlyRate;

    public double hoursPerWeek;

    public HourlyEmployee() {
    }

    public double getBiWeeklyPay() {
        return hourlyRate * (hoursPerWeek *2);
    }

    public double getHourlyRate() {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate) {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getHoursPerWeek() {
        return hoursPerWeek;
    }

    public void setHoursPerWeek(double hoursPerWeek) {
        this.hoursPerWeek = hoursPerWeek;   
    }   
}
```

**SalaryEmployee.java**

```
package salary;
public class SalaryEmployee extends Employee {

    public SalaryEmployee() {
    }

    public double salary;

    public double getBiWeeklyPay() {
        return salary/(52*2) ;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

**TestEmployee.java**

```
package salary;
import java.util.*;

public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    java.util.ArrayList<Employee> employees = new java.util.ArrayList<Employee>();

    SalaryEmployee john = new SalaryEmployee();
    john.setFullName("John Doe");
    john.setSalary(50000.00);
    employees.add(john);

    HourlyEmployee bob = new HourlyEmployee();
    bob.setFullName("Bob Smith");
    bob.setHourlyRate(15.00);
    bob.setHoursPerWeek(20.00);
    employees.add(bob);

    HourlyEmployee Joe = new HourlyEmployee();
    Joe.setFullName("Joe Moe");
    Joe.setHourlyRate(27.00);
    Joe.setHoursPerWeek(45.00);
    employees.add(Joe);

    HourlyEmployee Doe = new HourlyEmployee();
    Doe.setFullName("Doe Joe");
    Doe.setHourlyRate(20.00);
    Doe.setHoursPerWeek(25.00);
    employees.add(Doe);

    print(employees);

    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<Employee> employees){   
        for(Employee e: employees){
          e.printgetBiWeeklyPay();
        }
    }

}
```

Employee, salary, hourly were mostly premade along with TestEmployee i was instructed. I read through my textbook and my teachers lectures, and everything seems to be in order. Hopefully someone could give me a  hint and i will have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void printgetBiWeeklyPay() {
   System.out.println("Employee "+this.fullName+ "'s"+ "Bi-weekly pay is:");
}
```

Referring to your code above, your method printgetBiWeeklyPay() just did what you have mentioned, printing the employee name and bi-weekly pay but without the number... Can you see that you are missing the crucial variable in the print statement? Where is your variable for biweekly pay? You never call it, hence no output of the biweekly pay is produced.

Perhaps:

```
public void printgetBiWeeklyPay() {
   System.out.print("Employee "+this.fullName+ "'s"+ "Bi-weekly pay is:" + String.valueOf(this.getBiWeeklyPay());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i can't believe i missed something that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you improve the implementation of printgetBiWeeklyPay() by actually invoking the intended method.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i can't believe i missed that.